# “Are” Vs “Is” in the following sentences

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects, quantifiers

I'm confused what verb would concord in the following couple of sentences:

> The number of students and the number of teachers **are/is** decreasing
>   day by day in the school.
>
> Either a number of teachers or a number of students **is/are**
>   participating in the college's festival.

According to my understanding *the number of* is always followed by a singular verb even two *the number of* are joined with *and*. Also, *a number is* always followed by a plural verb. So I think the former will take *is* while the latter concord with *are.* But I'm not sure.

Comment: The first one is very awkward.  If this is a real, specific example from something you're writing, I'd suggest just re-phrasing the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first sentence, you are talking about two things, the number of students and the number of teachers. Let's call them A and B as a shorthand.

> - A and B is decreasing
> - A and B are decreasing

The second form is obviously correct:

> The number of students and the number of teachers are decreasing day by day in the school.

In your second sentence, you are again talking of two things, and choosing between them:

> - Either A or B is decreasing
> - Either A or B are decreasing

In this case the first is correct. A potential difficulty arises because both A and B refer to ***a number of particular people*** which could be construed as a plural. So either is potentially correct. Most people would match the verb to the word immediately preceding it and use "students are".

> Either a number of teachers or a number of students is participating in the college's festival.
>   Either a number of teachers or a number of students are participating in the college's festival.

Comment: Not really.  If you're just eliding "A [is decreasing] and..." then *is* would be correct.  When your subjects are as short as 'A' and 'B' then you're probably not eliding but for the first example sentence, I'd say that's the most natural interpretation.

Comment: The sentence as given does not elide. It specifically mentions two numbers. If you want to change the sentence to "the number of students and teachers" then that's changing it.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't elide?  The elided words wouldn't appear.  It's a matter of how you interpret it.

Comment: What? "The number of students and the number of teachers [verb]" is not eliding anything.

Comment: "The number of students [is decreasing] and..."

Comment: The bus is red and the coach is red. The bus and the coach are red.

Comment: Again, "bus" and "coach" are short and snappy and so it clearly seems like they are being combined together to form a group of two in that sentence.  For longer noun phrases like "the number of x", it's not so clear.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: So in the second question both *are* and *is* is acceptable?

Comment: Both *are* and *is* **are** acceptable (not *is acceptable*!) depending on whether you are talking of the number as a single entity or a group of individuals.

Comment: The colour of the bus and the colour of the coach are red?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to decide whether “a number of people” should itself be construed to be singular or plural.   Compare these two example sentences to find the right answer:

> - A number of people **has** come to the same realization.
> - A number of people **have** come to the same realization.

Which one of those is right?  It is clear that only *have* works there, not **has*.  The explanation is more complicated, though.

The reason for this is that “a number of” functions as a pre-modifier to the noun phrase, just as “a lot of” does. That means it works like an adjective, and it therefore cannot change the grammatical number of the subject in a way that affects verb agreement.

Therefore in all cases you have given, the subject of your sentences is plural.

Comment: This explanation applies only to the second example in the question.  In the first example, the number itself is a subject of the verb, not merely a modifiers.  The plural in the first sentences comes because there are two numbers, as explained in other answers.

Answer (score -2):

Is the subject singular or plural?  In the first example, the subject of the sentence is "**the** number", which is singular; "the number [...] is decreasing".  In the second, the subject is "**a** number of...", which is plural; "a number of [x] are participating".

Comment: I've seen people using *are*  in the first sentence. This is referring to the number (ie as a concept of the numeric system), but there are two of these numbers under discussion, so *are* is the only correct option.

Comment: I don't agree; that example sentence merely elides "is decreasing" for the first "number".  To pluralize it, you'd need to say something like "The numbers of students and teachers are decreasing".