# Subject-Verb Agreement - was/were

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

A bag of carrots and half a tomato "was/were" sitting on the kitchen counter.

A bag of carrots and half a tomato **was** sitting on the kitchen counter.  Is this correct?

I was informed that the main subject is "bag," so I should be using the singular verb. Also, is "of carrots and half a tomato" the prepositional phrase? or is it just "of carrots"?  Is this correct as well?  Please advise.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118359/are-vs-is-in-the-following-sentences

Comment: I count two subjects.  Dunno where you learned to count.

Comment: lol I thought so...thanks for your guidance!  I am currently taking an outline grammar course for fun.  Apparently, i am wasting my money on this course.  Please see below for the instructor's response: 

"The subject of the sentence will not appear within a prepositional phrase.
So first, you must cross out the prepositional phrase to find the subject:
"of carrots and half a tomato"
What is left is "a bag".
"Bag" is the true subject of the sentence. It is singular (only one).So, the verb must also be singular: was"

Comment: @JasonSmith: If the sentence could mean that, it would be ambiguous and there would be two correct answers.  But you cannot have "a bag of half a tomato".  It is therefore clear to a native speaker that "half a tomato" is not a joint object of the preposition, as the instructor supposes, but a joint subject of the verb "was sitting".  Cross out the prepositional phrase, sure; it is "of carrots".  You are left with "a bag and half a tomato".

Comment: @BenVoigt: I agree! She also noted, "When you have a mixed series of items where one is plural and the other singular, use the last item, the one closest to the verb to achieve subject verb agreement, which in this case is:half a tomato (singular)." I believe she is using the “proximity rule.”  Would it be correct in this case?

Comment: @Jason: No.  That rule affects person, not plurality.  "Two items are/were sitting on the counter." so therefore "A bag and a half tomato are/were sitting on the counter."

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thanks so much!  I was going crazy trying to figure out why she would use "was."  Super thanks all :)

Comment: Jason Smith, conjoined subjects typically take plural agreement.  This is no exception and *were* is the better choice, but consider sentences like "drinking and driving is a dangerous combination" or "peanut butter and jelly is my favorite flavor".  Unfortunately there is no simple and general answer.  @GeorgePompidou The subject is the noun phrase *a bag of carrots and half a tomato*.  I'm sure the OP can count; please [**Be Nice**](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).